# vscode- how do I select an entire section of folded code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I fold a section of code (using > in margin) and then try to copy or cut that entire section of folded code, vscode only selects the first line and ignores the rest of the folded code. How can I select and entire section of folded code, without the need to expand the folded section before selection?

[expanded][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2B7BQ.png

[image: folded]

[image: result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try selecting till the next line, below the fold :

[image]

Comment: You beauty. Thanks. That was such a dumb mistake to make. Thanks again

Comment: No problem ! :)

Comment: @gdcodes There is no next line in my case. How else can I select the entire collapsed code in VS Code. Thanks